# How disable VirtualizingStackPanel in LongListSelector?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

i want disable VirtualizingStackPanel in LongListSelector.
I try this:

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
```

but doesn't work (app crashes)...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
```

is read only property.

use

```
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```